# Display UITableView NSArray in alphabetical order

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, ipod

How to display UITableView in alphabetical order, similar to the way iPod.app does with the sections and the sectionIndex. I have searched in Apple documentation without success. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you would only like to sort an array of strings alphabetically, you can achieve it by:

> sortedArray = [originalArray
>   sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"me", @"you", @"her", nil];

[myArray sortedArrayByPerformingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```